# Joining 2 objects, but I get a weird shading issue

Tags: shaders, geometry

Good evening,

I have a question about joining 2 objects.
I am currently working on a tire project and want to connect 2 different objects, but I get a weird shading issue like you can see in this picture.
[image]
Here is also a picture of the geometry.
I used the SStep option from Hard Ops. (Autosmooth 60°)

vexE

Edit:

I basically have those two opjects, I want to connect together.
[image: Pic 1]
They are joined together and they have a Mirror, Bevel, an Array modifier and Auto Smooth at 60°(No Modifier->The option from the Data Tab).
Now I want to connect the geometry of those 2 joined objects so I can bevel the edges, but I get this shading issue, as shown above. I hope you understand what I mean. I cant upload the blend file, because this is a client work...

I just figured it out. I added a solidify modifier, connected both meshes and removed the geometry you cant see.
Thank you for your effort @Tak and @Duarte Farrajota Ramos

Comment: Hard to tell from those screenshot alone, looks like you removed doubles, and it joined to vertex from the different surfaces. Please edit your question and provide more information on what you did, more screenshots, or possibly a blend file.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos I just saw your command, I will make some screenshots tomorrow and add some information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. Select these vertices using <kbd>C</kbd>
3. Smooth selected vertices using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: When I do what you told me, I get this result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci9dJ.png

Comment: Well, could you upload your .blend file to be able to help you? It's hard to keep guessing.

Comment: I will try this in a second

Comment: @vexE Could you please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful?

Comment: This wasn't helpful. I figured the problem out myself.